is there a way in Dash Plotly python to use dl.ImageOverlay with URL that requires authentication header?
I'm trying to download image from an api that requires an authentication header into dl.ImageOverlay using url argument.
If the api is public it is a simple take just to put the url int dl.ImageOverlay and it will get the image, but in my case I need to pass api key in the header.
I tried to dowanload the image then create file URL using Path library, but the browser didn't have the permission to open a localfile.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
